# How to extract all characters between last and second last spaces?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have for example the following column:

| col1 |
| --- |
| A B C D E |
| A B C E |
| A B C |

I want to get the following:

| col1 |
| --- |
| D |
| C |
| B |

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexp_extract:

with mytable as (
select 'A B C D E' col1 union all
select 'A B C E'  union all
select 'A B C'
)

select regexp_extract(col1, '\s+([^\s]+)\s+[^\s]*$',1) from mytable

Result:

```
D
    
C
    
B
```

Regex `'\\s+([^\\s]+)\\s+[^\\s]*$'` means:

`\\s+`        - space 1+ times

`([^\\s]+)`   - group to extract, not space 1+ times

`\\s+`        - 1+ space

`[^\\s]*`     - not a space any times

`enter code here`$           - end of the string

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code.

```
select split('A B C D E',' ')[ length('A B C D E')- length(replace('A B C D E',' ','') )-1 ] col
```

`split` - this is going to choose particular string based on spaces.
`length` - This is used intelligently to calculate last string before last space.
`length (whole string ) - length (whole string without spaces)` - This should give you number of spaces. Do a -1 to get last but one space count.